# Accessing interface method defined in .m file

Tags: objective-c

MyClass.h file

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 
@interface MyClass : NSObject

{
    // This is the Place of Instance Variable
}

- (void)thePublicMethod;
@end
```

MyClass.m file

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@interface MyClass()

- (void)thePrivateMethod;

@end

@implementation MyClass 

-(void)thePublicMethod {
    NSLog(@"Public Method Called");
}

- (void)thePrivateMethod {
    NSLog(@"Private Method Called");
}


@end
```

The main.m file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyClass.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        MyClass *myObj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
        [myObj  thePublicMethod];
       // [myObj  thePrivateMethod];        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**since “Private” methods can be created by defining them in a class’s implementation file while omitting them from its interface file.**
i want to access thePrivateMethod from main.m and also can i call thePrivateMethod() from thePublicMethod() is it possible and how ?

Comment: Note that `thePrivateMethod()` is not typical nomenclature for referring to methods.   Just call it `-thePrivateMethod`.

Comment: doing this  [myObj  thePrivateMethod]; throws compilation error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access an internal method from somewhere other than the class's implementation, then you need to truly declare it as a private method.

Move that class extension to its own header file, say `MyClass_Private.h`.  Then `#import` that header into both `main.m` and `MyClass.m`.

I.e. move this:

```
@interface MyClass()

- (void)thePrivateMethod;

@end
```

Into a file called `MyClass_Private.h` and then `#import "MyClass_Private.h"` in both your `MyClass.m` and `main.m` files.

---

**Internal** means *only used in the innards of this framework or class*.

**Private** means *may be used by this framework or the class, but may be exposed to clients that are more intimately tied to the class than through Public API*.  Typically reserved for framework authors on large scale systems (like the OS).

**Public** means *may be used anywhere by any client of the class*.

Comment: “Private” methods can be created by defining them in a class’s implementation file while omitting them from its interface file. how can i access it ?

Comment: By putting the "private" declaration in a different header file and `#import`ing it in both your class's implementation file and wherever else you want to access it.

Answer (score 0):

*No matter how* **or** *where* **or IF** you declare a method, at all..  If it **exists**..  calling it is as simple as

```
[myInstance performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"yourSuperSecretMethod:") 
                 withObject:myKillerObject];
```

If the method got compiled.. It will get called.  There is no "hiding" it. Even if not declared, the runtime "gives up" this information to any interested party.  [@see class-dump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/%E2%80%8E), if interested in learning more.

Comment: Well, yeah, you can do that... but, don't. :)